# Getting information from Event

Tags: java, text, swt, listener

I'm using ModifyListener to get information from Text that changes.

Is there a way to get the Text's text in the listener (like a method of Event e)?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the listener on a JTextField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next example helps you :

```
Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE);
text.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

    @Override
    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
        Text source = (Text) e.getSource();
        System.out.println("text = " + source.getText());
    }
});
text.pack();
```

According to [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/ModifyEvent.html) `e.getSource()` return:

> The object on which the Event initially occurred.